# Winsorize outliers

Tags: python, dataframe, outliers

I have a dataframe of 200,000 observations and 23 different columns. I plotted the data and found out that there were outliers in every columns. Therefore, I want to winsorize the complete dataframe. At first, my code did work. It was slow though.  However, now I only get the message that 'Series' object is not callable. How can I fix this?

I use the following code to winsorize the dateframe:

`lower = 0.01
 upper = 0.99
 quantile_df = df.quantile([lower,upper])
 quant_df`

After defining the quartiles, I filter the outliers out of the dataframe:

```
df =df.apply(lambda x: x(x > quant_df.loc[lower,x.name]) & 
                                (x < quant_df.loc[upper,x.name]), axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, you are trying to filter out outliers for each column.
So you can iterate over the columns, and filter each time:

```
for target_col in df.columns:
    # get upper/lower bound
    df['lower'], df['upper']= df[target_col].quantile([lower, upper])
    # filter
    df = df[(df[target_col] > df['lower']) & (df[target_col] < df['upper'])]
```

You might need to change df.columns to any subset of it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! When I try it this way,  I get an error saying: " unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'int". If I replace it with "and", I get the message: "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()". I still don't know how to fix this.

Comment: @JulianLo Hey I just edit it. The reason for the error is that & has higher priority during excecution. So to have 2 conditions work together we need to keep them in ().

Comment: Hi, maybe you could help me with an additional question. When I winsorize the specific column, Python removes the complete row in the dataframe. As a result, columns that need to be winsorized later on will winsorized multiple times by this code. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: So you might just want a copy of the result? or you can simply add a column storing the result mask

Comment: I need the winsorized data for calculations later on. If I perform the code on the whole dataframe, a whole row is deleted whenever one value is an outlier. That is not my intention. Performing the winsorize process to all columns one by one and storing the results in a new dataframe is quite a big activity.  Do you know a faster way to do this?

Comment: Each column you can generate a mask. you can repeatedly do & on the mask((df[target_col] > df['lower']) & (df[target_col] < df['upper'])).